# Parallel programming languages which look deterministic?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, dc.parallel-comp

Are there any programming languages where the system parallelizes the program without any noticeable differences for the programmer?

That is, the programmer writes a linear, deterministic program, without any additional tags or meta-data, and the underlying system parallelizes all of the work.

Comment: Ask it on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the "without any additional tags or meta-data" part, but I know that recent versions of Matlab make it pretty easy to parallelize your code by simply adding the "par" keyword to your for loops (see the [Matlab help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/parfor.html) for more info).

This is as close to having no "noticeable differences for the programmer" that I'm aware of.

Comment: See also the language Cilk (http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/cilk/) for a more comprehensive effort along these lines.